# JSON - How to get specific value inside array?

Tags: javascript, json, api

Given the below response, how would I get things like title?

```
jsonFlickrFeed({
    "title": "Thing",
    "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/",
    "description": "",
    "items": [
   {
        "title": "Title",
        "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/123",
        "media": {"m":"http://farm6.staticflickr.com/123.jpg"},
   },
   {
        "title": "Title2",
        "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/1234",
        "media": {"m":"http://farm6.staticflickr.com/1234.jpg"},
   },
})
```

I want to do something like:

```
for (var i=0; i<xml.responseText.length;i++) {
    var x = (xml.responseText.items.title[i]);
    document.write(x)
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: this is incomplete code. are we to infer that xml.responseText is some result of this mysterious jsonFlickrFeed function?

Comment: @hubsonbropa xml.responseText results in the above jsonFlickrFeed

Comment: @hubsonbropa The jsonFlickrFeed is what I get when I console.log(xml.responseText)... Wondering how to get specific things within jsonFlickrFeed

Comment: I'm not following what you mean by 'within'. I assume this function returns a javascript object and that you want to introspect that object. right?

Answer (score 1):

assuming xml.responseText is not null and is the defined result of the function in your question...
reference the responseText.items length, not responseText. Then move your index from title to items:

```
for (var i=0; i < xml.responseText.items.length; i++) {
    var x = xml.responseText.items[i].title;
    document.write(x)
}
```

Comment: The jsonFlickrFeed is what I get when I console.log(xml.responseText)... Wondering how to get specific things within jsonFlickrFeed